# max_connections option not working with mysqld

Tags: mysql, file, connection-pooling

I have setup `max_connections=2000` in `/etc/my.conf` and restarted `mysqld`

but still `max_connections` apear to be stuck at `412`

```
mysql>  SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "max_connections";
+-----------------+-------+
| Variable_name   | Value |
+-----------------+-------+
| max_connections | 412  |
+-----------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

I have also tried restarting `mysqld` post

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL max_connections = 2000;
```

but in I still get the `max_connections | 412` from the query `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "max_connections";`

Comment: Sharing this as knowledge QA. Please edit the existing answer only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by changing system level limit on number of open files.

Check the system level. run command `ulimit -a` output will be

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 31168
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1012
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 4096
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

the `open files` limit has to be more than value of `max_connecitons`

To change that do the following

```
 sudo nano /etc/security/limits.conf
```

and add/edit

```
 *   hard    nofile  4096
 *   soft    nofile  4096
```

Now re-login to the server and restart `mysqld` and check

```
mysql>  SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "max_connections";
+-----------------+-------+
| Variable_name   | Value |
+-----------------+-------+
| max_connections | 2000  |
+-----------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: This helped me. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

1. Create an override for the service file

   `systemctl edit mysql.service`
2. Add the following content

```
    [Service]
    LimitNOFILE=4096
```

3. Restart the MySQL server

   `service mysql restart`